# How to plot a histogram with unequal widths without computing it from raw data?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

Matplotlib's [`hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) says "Compute and draw the histogram of x".  I'd like to make a plot *without* computing anything first.  I have the bin widths (unequal), and the total amount in each bin, and I want to plot a frequency-quantity histogram.

For instance, with the data

```
cm      Frequency
65-75   2
75-80   7
80-90   21
90-105  15
105-110 12
```

It should make a plot like this:

[image: Histogram]

http://www.gcsemathstutor.com/histograms.php

where the area of the blocks represents the frequency in each class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working on the same as David Zwicker:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

freqs = np.array([2, 7, 21, 15, 12])
bins = np.array([65, 75, 80, 90, 105, 110])
widths = bins[1:] - bins[:-1]
heights = freqs.astype(np.float)/widths
    
plt.fill_between(bins.repeat(2)[1:-1], heights.repeat(2), facecolor='steelblue')
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram using fill_between]

Answer (score 3):

You want a [bar chart](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.sort(np.random.rand(6))
y = np.random.rand(5)

plt.bar(x[:-1], y, width=x[1:] - x[:-1], align='edge')

plt.show()
```

Here `x` contains the edges of the bars and `y` contains the height (not the area!). Note that there is one more element in `x` than in `y` because there is one more edge than there are bars.

[image]

With original data and area calculation:

```py
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequencies = np.array([2, 7, 21, 15, 12])
bins = np.array([65, 75, 80, 90, 105, 110])

widths = bins[1:] - bins[:-1]
heights = frequencies/widths

plt.bar(bins[:-1], heights, width=widths, align='edge')

plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with unequal widths]

Comment: Is there a way to get the same effect as `histtype='stepfilled'`?

Comment: These examples don't work anymore. Default location of bars has changed?